# How to set date in materializecss using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, materialize

```
<div class="input-field col s4" style="max-height: 58px;">
                   <input id="email" name="email" type="email" maxlength="30" class="validate" required length='30' disabled="true">
                   <label for="email" data-error="Invalid Email ID">Email ID</label>
                </div>
<div class="input-field col s4" style="max-height: 58px;">
                   <input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" class="datepicker" required>
                   <label for="dob" data-error="Invalid Date of Birth">Date of Birth</label>
                </div>
```

I tried to set values in text fields it worked

```
$('#email').attr('value', result.result.Email);
$('#email').next().addClass('active');
```

How will I set date ?

I tried this

```
$('#dob').attr('value', result.result.DoB);
$('#dob').next().addClass('active');
```

It didnt work. Then I tried this

```
$('#dob').val(result.result.DoB);
$('#dob').next().addClass('active');
```

It is setting date but its overlapping label.

[image]

**Also how to set it to different formats like June 17, 1995**

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually use that type of input. Are you sure that it returns a displayable value? Try adding the toString method.

```
$('#dob').val(result.result.DoB.toString());
$('#dob').next().addClass('active');
```

Comment: I always used like this `result.result.DoB`  only 100 of times in my project. It is working. Is there anything wrong using like this ?

Comment: Still I am getting same output.

Comment: Try to console.log the value of result.result.DoB and let me see the result.

Comment: 1995-11-11
string

             console.log(result.result.DoB);
                console.log(typeof(result.result.DoB));

Comment: $('#dob').val(new Date(result.result.DoB).toString());

Try that code, or you should consider using the momentJS.

Comment: I am able to display date. Problem is with overlapping. Thanks using this date I can set it in different format but still overlapping is there.

Answer (score 0):

**Working DEMO** - https://jsfiddle.net/dxbfhdzg/2/

**For the overlapping issue,**

I have kept the `<label>` tags before the `<div>` tags.

Like this,

```
<label for="email" data-error="Invalid Email ID">Email ID</label>
<div class="input-field col s4" style="max-height: 58px;">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" maxlength="30" class="validate" required length='30'>
</div>
<label for="dob" data-error="Invalid Date of Birth">Date of Birth</label>
<div class="input-field col s4" style="max-height: 58px;">
    <input type="date" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

**And for formatting the date like June 17, 1995,**

You need to use the **format** attrubte while initializing your datepicker, and you can further use the **.set** method to set your **result.result.DoB** value something like this,

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    format: 'mmmm dd, yyyy' });

 var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
 picker.set('select',  new Date('17 June, 1995'));
```

Comment: but placeholder will replace the label. After entering value I cant see it

Comment: Okay got it. I have updated my answer above and the JSFiddle link. Can you please check it now?

Answer (score 0):

Here code looks like

```
<div class="input-field col s4" style="max-height: 58px;">
                   <input id="studentDOB" name="studentDOB" type="date" class="datepicker" required>
                   <label for="studentDOB" data-error="Invalid Date of Birth">Date of Birth</label>
                </div>
```

But when I checked in developer console, I found this

[image]

So it has got a new div tag too and `active` got added into that element but we want `active` tag into label

so use the following line

`$('#studentDOB').parent().children('label').addClass('active');`

For formatting, you can use get method of javascript

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
d = new Date(result.result.DoB);
date = d.getDate() + " " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ", " + d.getFullYear();
$('#studentDOB').val(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you managed to set the date value already here's for the overlapping issue. I added the "input-label" class to all the labels and then whenever an input box is not empty jQuery will automatically add an "active" class to the label to give way to the value. Like so:

```
// my label
<label class="input-label" for="bday">Birthday</label>

// how to move up your label
$('.input-label').addClass('active');

// how to check all your inputs if they're empty or not
// if not, make the labels active
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() != ""){
        $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").addClass('active');
        // or if you want to target id instead
        $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").addClass('active');
   }
});
```